# raspberry pi 4 can you rotate second display?

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, retropie

I have a 28" stretchbar display connected to the second hdmi port on my pi4. Is there a way to rotate that display 180 degrees and nto the main display on the first hdmi port?

This lcd screen I am using is: 28 inch Stretched Bar LCD Panel DV280FBM-NB1 from Amazon. There is an option in the function set for "Picture Rotate" but this does nothing when setting it to 180.. When I mounted the monitor I assumed this would work. Need to mount so that the cables routed in the up direction.. I can take it off but it will be a PITA to do (used hot glue to mount in frame).

Comment: Forgot to mention, running retropie..  I can flip the screen in desktop but it doesn't work for retropie

Comment: I ended up just removing the screen and re-mounting in the correct position.

Comment: Please don't use comments to improve your question. Instead edit it and add it there.